# "Close as off-topic" references webapps.

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

Comment: What? (padding for minimum characters)

Comment: The second option - "Questions on Web Apps are expected to generally relate to web applications, within the scope defined in the faq"

Comment: I think that the image you provided will only be shown on the beta site.

Comment: @TomWij I checked, the other beta sites show the correct text. And we have had bugs of this sort on them aswell. They were corrected after being posted.

Comment: Quotes are your friend! Pretend this post has the following topic: "Close as off-topic" references webapps.